# Thread safe deletion of node in a linked list

Tags: c++, multithreading, data-structures, linked-list, shared-ptr

If I have three threads that run the following linked list:

```
A1-->B1-->C1-->D
A2-->B2-->C2-->D (same D)
A3-->B3-->C3-->D (same D)
```

this is the `DTOR`:

```
node::~node()
{
    if (next) {
        delete next;
        next= NULL;
    }
}
```

I also have a `linkedListFactory` class who has `createChain()` function.
The `createChain()` called on loop from outside class.

what is the bast way to delete the linked list with thread safety ?
Is there other solution beside `shared_ptr` ? maybe to hold all the shared nodes in a `vector<node*>` and call the `DTOR` only after all the "regular" nodes were deleted ?

Thank you very much

Comment: I don't understand the question. How did B and D end up as common elements in the three linked lists? How does B link to C1, C2 and C3 if it only has one next ptr?

Comment: C1, C2 and C3 are therefore owning D. shared_ptr is perfect for managing shared ownership. There are other ways to manage this but without knowing why shared_ptr is not appropriate it is difficult to suggest an alternative.

Comment: D is not in the code right now and it's all implemented with base class pointers (A,B,C,D inherit from the base class). So before I'm replacing everything to shared_ptr, I would like to know if I'm missing other directions.

Comment: [OT]: deleting null pointer is valid, so the test is unneeded.

Comment: Acesss to the node needs to be thread safe because otherwise multiple threads might delete concurrently. Access to the next pointer also needs to be synchronised.

Comment: I will use shared pointers, thanks everyone.